# Vuejs and Laravel - array turns into object - can't get length

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js

I've created a favorites component.

I hit endpoints with axios to get items the user add or delete in session. A simple badge returns the length of the favorites prop (which is a json array of objects) returned by the endpoint.

When the user delete the last item he added no problem, the endpoint returns me a fresh new array and the length is updated. But if he tries to delete another (let's say the second added), the prop turns into an object of objects, and the lenght is like null, but there are still the other items in the list.

I tried to declare the prop as an object but still same problem.

CODE :

delete method in Vue:

```
deleteFavorite(index) {
        axios.delete('/deleteFavorite/'+index)
        .then(response => { this.favorites = response.data })
        .catch(error => { console.log(error) });
    },
```

delete method in laravel controller :

```
public function deleteFavorite(Request $request,$index) 
{
    $request->session()->forget('favorites.'.$index);

    return response()->json(session('favorites'));
}
```

My component (favorites is a prop) :

```
<template>
<li class="nav-item dropdown" id="liFavorites">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="favoritesDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbtack text-primary" id="favoritesIcon"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-primary" v-if="favorites.length"><small>{{favorites.length}}</small></span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu py-0" aria-labelledby="favoritesDropdown">
        <span class="dropdown-item py-3" v-for="(item, index) in favorites" :key="index">
            {{item.nom}} <br>
            {{item.modele}} <br>
            <span v-for="(option, indexOpt) in item.options" :key="indexOpt">{{option}}</span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-2" @click.prevent="$emit('delete-item',index)"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Any help very welcome !

Comment: Hi,can you share your code ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, i added code

Comment: When deleting an item from a 0-indexed array, you are actually changing the index of items coming after the deleted item in the array. Deleting `b` from `['a', 'b', 'c']` will change the index of `c` from `2` to `1`. Therefore you should update all items (or at least the ones starting at the deleted index) server-side. By ensuring the server also holds an array of items with consecutive indexes (i.e. no holes), no object will be returned when serializing to JSON. This only happens when some indexes are missing, i.e. `[0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 3 => 'c']` will yield the same issue.

Comment: Thanks Namoshek. When i die and dump the json response i can see the problem you tell me. when i put a 2nd item in session it becomes index 1. So if i try to delete the 1st, there is no index 0 anymore, i see the hole. is the right way to foreach on the session and reset all indexes ?